# Splitting kwargs between function calls

Tags: python, arguments, parameter-passing, keyword-argument

From time to time I face this dilemma. Suppose I have a function like this:

```
def foo(..., **kwargs):
    ...
    actor = make_actor(..., **a_kwargs)
    return actor.act(..., **b_kwargs)
```

I want to let the caller specify kwargs to pass to `make_actor()` (a_kwargs), and to `act()` (b_kwargs).  The problem is, of course, that `foo` can only take `**kwargs` once.

(In almost all cases a_kwargs and b_kwargs share no common keys, so we don't need to worry about param-name clashes).

I can think of several approaches, each with its own clear disadvantages/limitations.

```
def foo1(..., **kwargs):
    ...
    a_kwargs = {k:kwargs.pop(k) for k in kwargs.keys() if k in ['arg1','arg2',...]}
    actor = make_actor(..., **a_kwargs)
    return actor.act(..., **kwargs)

def foo2(..., arg1=DEFAULT1, arg2=DEFAULT2, ..., **b_kwargs):
    ...
    actor = make_actor(..., arg1=arg1, arg2=arg2, ...)
    return actor.act(..., **b_kwargs)

def foo3(..., a_kwargs={}, **b_kwargs):
    ...
    actor = make_actor(..., **a_kwargs)
    return actor.act(..., **b_kwargs)

def foo4(..., a_kwargs={}, b_kwargs={}):
    ...
    actor = make_actor(..., **a_kwargs)
    return actor.act(..., **b_kwargs)
```

Which is the most pythonic? Is there another approach I overlooked which is superior to the four above?

In the general case we might want to split kwargs for passing to more than two other functions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In general, the fourth option makes the most sense.

Even though it compromises on the ability to use `kwargs` in your main function, it makes the code clear, allows for future changes and reduces excessive listing of arguments. It also doesn't mean you have both an excessive list of `kwargs` and a dictionary going into the same function, which seems inconsistent.

`Simple is better than complex`, `Readability counts`, `practicality beats purity`